# Discord.py add reaction role issue

Tags: python, discord.py

I've started to create a bot for my discord, trying to add a role after a user's reaction, but I still have a 403 forbidden (error code 50013): Missing permission when I've already put in the right permissions (8) to the bot.

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 706945439945195551:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == 'montmo':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='membre')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ProgramData\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/bntth/Documents/Python/Projets/Bot discord/bot_elogic.py", line 47, in on_raw_reaction_add
    await member.add_roles(role)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 641, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 221, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Do you have any idea what might be causing this mistake? Did I forget something in the configuration or the code? 
Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bot's highest role has to be higher than the role you're attempting to add.

Consider this list of roles:

1. Admin
2. Bot
3. Moderator
4. Member

`Member` is the default. They're not able to assign `Moderator`, `Bot` or `Admin` to other members.
In the same way, people with `Moderator` won't be able to assign `Bot` or `Admin`, but *are* able to assign `Member` roles.
And if a bot with role `Bot` tried to assign `Admin` to another user, it wouldn't have the permissions to. However, it would have the permissions to assign `Moderator` and `Member` roles.

To fix this, just move the `Bot` role to the top of the list, and then it'll be able to assign all roles.

Comment: I knew it would be something silly and so obvious, that even in front of me, I would never have seen it. Thank you so much for your answer and your explanation